# Wont Commit after a directory change

Tags: git

I was having issues when running a rails server and it not connecting up to my localhost. I changed the location of a directory and that seemed to fix the problem.

Now though I don't seem to be able to git commit that project. I got the errors after command: 
git push origin master

```
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

After searching through and trying a number of ways people have listed to get around it and none of them working I decided to just delete the repository.

Now when trying to post up the project again I get this:

```
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

after a git init
git add .
git commit -m "etc"

Comment: What directory did you move? What does the directory layout look like? There isn't nearly enough information here for me to tell what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the message

```
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Means:

- You created a brand new git repository in the current directory (`git init`)
- You added all files (besides those in `.gitignore`) to the INDEX (`git add .`)
- You commited all files added to the INDEX (`git commit -m "etc"`)

Now you have no panding changes and you can continue hacking on your project. The new changes will be detected and showed by the git (`git status`) and can be commited to the repository in the same way

- `git add .` (or `git add -A .` to add removed files also)
- `git commit -m "..."`